# Recursive Parent-Child Relationship C#

Tags: c#, recursion, hierarchy

I am trying to build Hierarchy from .csv file, It consist of ID(Functional Location), Description & Parent  Id(SupFunctLoc) which are all in string. I have fetched the data into list.
Code & Data Sample For Reference.

```
 Functional Loc.    Description SupFunctLoc.
 70003  ABC AS002
 70C2   ABC 70003
 70C2.01    ABC 70C2
 70C2.01.02 ABC 70C2.01
 70C2.01.02.10  ABC 70C2.01.02
 70C2.01.02.10-BG010    ABC 70C2.01.02.10
```

Sample Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Input> inputList = new List<Input>();
        var yourData = File.ReadAllLines(locate)
               .Skip(1)
               .Select(x => x.Split(','))
               .Select(x => new Input()
               {
                   FunctionalLocation = x[0],
                   Description = x[1],
                   SuppFunctionalLocation = x[2],

               });
        //try 3

        //try 2

        var outputList = yourData
            .Where(i => i.SuppFunctionalLocation!= null) // Just get the parents
            .Select(i => new Input()
            {
                Description = i.Description,
                SuppFunctionalLocation = i.SuppFunctionalLocation,
                Children = inputList
                    .Where(x => x.FunctionalLocation.ToString() == i.SuppFunctionalLocation.ToString())
                    .Select(x => new Input()
                    {
                        Description = x.Description,
                        SuppFunctionalLocation = x.SuppFunctionalLocation,
                        FunctionalLocation = x.FunctionalLocation,
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList();


        foreach (var output in outputList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(output.Description);
            output.Children.ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine($"\t {c.Description}"));
        }
}
```

Class Defination for Input

```
 class Input
    {
        public string FunctionalLocation { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string SuppFunctionalLocation { get; set; }
        public List<Input> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

Please help what can be done in this case. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You're splitting on a `,`, but your sample text doesn't have commas. Also, you need to provide the class def for `Input`.

Comment: @Enigmativity hello I have pasted a sample of data and updated question with Class Input Defination

Comment: `Functional Loc.` is primary key?

Comment: foreach ( var item in collection ) item.Children = collection.Where( c => c.ParentId == item.Id ).ToList();

Comment: also: why i there a list of children? From what i can tell, there is always just one supfunc...

Comment: @nozzleman Because each item **can** have a lot of children (zero to unlimited)

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). your question has nothing to do with your headline, you don't show, what you tried... please improve question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var source = @"Functional Loc.    Description SupFunctLoc.
70003  ABC AS002
70C2   ABC 70003
70C2.01    ABC 70C2
70C2.01.02 ABC 70C2.01
70C2.01.02.10  ABC 70C2.01.02
70C2.01.02.10-BG010    ABC 70C2.01.02.10";

var lines =
    source
        .Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(x => x.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

var results =
    lines
        .Skip(1)
        .Select(x => new Input()
        {
            FunctionalLocation = x[0],
            Description = x[1],
            SuppFunctionalLocation = x[2],
        });

var lookup = results.ToLookup(x => x.SuppFunctionalLocation);

Func<string, List<Input>> build = null;
build = SuppFunctionalLocation =>
    lookup[SuppFunctionalLocation]
        .Select(x => new Input()
        {
            FunctionalLocation = x.FunctionalLocation,
            Description = x.Description,
            SuppFunctionalLocation = x.SuppFunctionalLocation,
            Children = build(x.FunctionalLocation),
        })
        .ToList();

List<Input> tree = build("AS002");
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have read all items into the collection build the parent relationship with

```
foreach ( var parent in inputlist )
{
    parent.Children = inputlist
        .Where( child => child.SuppFunctionalLocation == parent.FunctionalLocation )
        .ToList();
}
```

To get only the root elements you have to look for all items, that have no parent

```
var outputlist = inputlist
    .Where( child => !inputlist.Any( parent => parent.FunctionalLocation == child.SuppFunctionalLocation ) )
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Building a hierarchy from items with existing parent key is relatively easy. I abstracted it a bit from your sample, but it's basically the same.

The items to be put into hierarchy

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    // to be filled
    public IList<MyItem> Children { get; set; }
}
```

The code to construct the child lists.

```
// assumption: MyItem elements have all properties set except the children collection
ICollection<MyItem> items = GetMyItems();

var parentRelation = items.ToLookup(x => x.ParentId);
foreach (var item in items)
{
    item.Children = parentRelation[item.Id].ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... :)